# Calling T::new() from inside generic struct in Rust

Tags: generics, rust

Halp! Im a rust newbie and ive battled through a bunch of stuff over the last few days but cannot find any information about this.
I have a generic struct (which i have simplified down to illustrate the issue). I want to be able to create a struct that does a bunch of stuff with a std::collections::HashMap , HashSet , List etc
Im assuming i need to imply that T must implement a new method .. using a trait? or similar but searches just turn up basic stuff

```
public struct dude< T > {
    data : std::sync::Arc< T >,
}

impl < T > dude< T > {
    pub fn new() -> dude< T > {
        Reloader{ data : Arc::new( <T>::new() ) }
    }
}
```

Produces the following error:

```
<T>::new();
     ^^^ function or associated item not found in `T`
```

Comment: I also tried T::new(); which produces the same error :-(

Answer (score 7):

When you use functions on a generic in rust, you need to specify a trait bound that proivdes those functions.

For example what if I tried to call `Dude::new()` with a class that doesn't provide a `new` function? In some languages (like C++) this would be flagged as an error where you tried to actually create the instance - but in rust, there is a principle of locality of reasoning.

There is an existing trait that provides functionality like `new()` - `Default` - which provides `Default::default()` using that as a trait bound looks like this:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
pub struct Dude<T> {
    data : std::sync::Arc<T>,
}

impl<T:Default> Dude<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Dude<T> {
        Dude{ data : Arc::new( Default::default() ) }
    }
}
```

The Default trait is implemented already for many types, for any custom types you can easily derive it (and clippy even gives you a warning about not implementing it im many places).

Now I can write:

```
let dude: Dude<String> = Dude::new();
```

It probably makes sense implement this for `Dude` too, rather than provide new inside `Dude` itself.

```
impl<T:Default> Default for Dude<T> {
  fn default() -> Dude<T> {
    Dude{ data : Arc::new( Default::default() ) }
  }
}
```

Comment: your answer explain how to do it but clearly should advice to use a trait like Default instead of introduce a new trait that already exist in std.

Comment: Agreed - somehow I forgot about something as simple as default. I'll fix that now.

Comment: Perfect - works like a bought one, thank you Michael :)

Comment: @Stargateur I mean, default is great and all but don't miss the forest for the trees. Default is certainly one way to make an object with zero parameters, but there are an infinite other ways to make an object with zero parameters too, that may not be default. In many cases, accepting a function to call to get the object allows one to e.g. curry the constructor.

Comment: @GManNickG I didn't says use a generic function was bad... I just talking about the New trait. the common pattern is to have a `_with` method like https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize_with for this kind of feature